# Selecting minimum date in data set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set that i am attempting to select the first record with a station id of 2.

```
InspectionNbr   Station          DateTimeStamp
825065             1            2010-11-16 04:38:49.000
825065             2            2010-11-16 12:38:31.000
825065             2            2010-12-06 01:35:14.000
825065             2            2011-01-24 08:11:04.000
```

In this case i want to select the second line of the results. How can i use SQL to get the minimum date where stationid = 2?

That being stated, this is what i have.
i created a temporary table in SQL. i have it setup to populate the table with the latest date. Then i attempt and update the temporary table with the following code

```
UPDATE @report_out 
 set    
DateTimeStamp = Min(si.CreatedDate)
 from
@report_out as r
 INNER JOIN
StationInspection as si
    on si.ModifiedDate = r.DateTimeStamp
where
r.Station = 2
```

For some reason beyond me it doesn't like the DateTimeStamp = Min(si.CreatedDate)
i get the follwing error:
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

any pointers?

Comment: I've re-tagged as `sql-server` guided by your question history, correct it yourself if it's wrong. Remember that SQL does not belong to Microsoft ;-)

Comment: What is the structure of @report_out, does it have multiple rows? It looks like you want every row to be updated to the min date for station 2 is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can figure out, an aggregate can't be used in an update statement because the aggregate and the update affect two different row sets.  Think about a normal SELECT with an aggregate:

```sql
SELECT MIN(CreatedDate)
FROM StationInspection
WHERE Station = 2
```

The aggregate works on all rows in the row set.  The row set is determined by the WHERE clause, which determines which rows will be in the row set.

In an update statement, the WHERE clause determines which rows will be *changed*:

```sql
UPDATE StationInspection
SET CreatedDate = @newDate
WHERE Station = 2
```

The update affects all rows in the row set (all rows that pass the filter specified by the WHERE clause).

So, in the case where you try to do both (I realize this is somewhat simplified from your code, but it makes the point):

```sql
UPDATE StationInspection
SET CreatedDate = MIN(CreatedDate)
WHERE Station = 2
```

You have two operations that require unique row sets, but only one *row set selector* (WHERE clause).

SQL doesn't support two WHERE clauses in a single statement.  So you'll need two statements:

```sql
DECLARE @newDate datetime

SELECT @newDate = SELECT MIN(CreatedDate)
FROM StationInspection
WHERE Station = 2

UPDATE StationInspection
SET CreatedDate = @newDate
WHERE Station = 2
```

Comment: @P Daddy, that worked! it seems like there is a better way, but for my level of understanding it was PERFECT. thanks for you help, i learned something good while doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If DateTimeStap is a candidate key (at least when composed with Station), then there is no need to create a temp table; just do:

```
Select a.* from a join 
(select a.Station, Min(a.DateTimeStamp) as m group by a.Station) as b 
on a.Station = b.Station and a.DateTimeStamp = b.m
```

then you've got StationID and minimum DateTimeStamp for all Stations. This is a fast Query.

If DateTimeStamp is not a candidate key... The query becomes slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the Record with Station id '2' and having minimum date, just try:

```
SELECT InspectionNbr, Station, DateTimeStamp
FROM   StationInspection
WHERE  Station = 2
AND    DateTimeStamp = (
                          SELECT MIN(DateTimeStamp) 
                          FROM   StationInspection 
                          WHERE  Station = 2
                       )
```

This way Eliminates Grouping

Answer (score 0):

```
select T.InspectionNbr,
       T.Station,
       T.DateTimeStamp
from (
       select *,
              row_number() over(order by DateTimeStamp) as rn
       from StationInspection
       where Station = 2
     ) as T
where T.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter statement for some DBs (notably MySQL) might be:

```
SELECT   InspectionNbr, Station, DateTimeStamp
FROM     StationInspection
WHERE    Station = 2
ORDER BY DateTimeStamp ASC
LIMIT    1
```